# NameError: name 'classroom_list' is not defined

Tags: python, pycharm

```
class Classroom:
    classroom_list=None

    @staticmethod
    def search_classroom(class_room):
        global classroom_list
        for classroom in classroom_list:
            if(classroom==class_room):
                return "Found"
            else:
                return -1
c=Classroom()

Classroom.classroom_list=['w','e','d','o']
Classroom.search_classroom('w')
```

Comment: did you mean `c.classroom_list`?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: You need to add some explanation about the error you are having and what your cede is expected to do

Comment: You should use it as `Classroom.classroom_list`

Answer (score 2):

I think you're over-complicating things, I think it can be much easier as such.

```
class Classroom:
    def __init__(self, classroom_list):
        self.classroom_list = classroom_list

    def search_classroom(self, class_room):
        return "Found" if class_room in self.classroom_list else -1

c = Classroom(['w','e','d','o'])
c.search_classroom('g')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `global classroom_list`, your function is looking for `classroom_list` in the outermost scope:

```
@staticmethod
def search_classroom(class_room):
    global classroom_list    # here
    for classroom in classroom_list:
```

.. there is no classroom_list defined there.

Instead, use the `@classmethod` decorator to do what you want, as it'll give you a reference to the current class as its first parameter:

```
@classmethod
def search_classroom(cls):
    for classroom in cls.classroom_list:
```

You can then iterate across the referenced property in the class, as you've assigned values to it outside.

However, you probably want to rewrite this to use an object and an instance property instead of a class property.